# Making a protective copy of JPA Entity

Tags: java, spring, jpa, clone

In my Spring application, I have code that reads in XML, then fetches for example an Organization entity via JPA and then updates the fields found in the XML to the Organization and returns the Organization.

But with code like this:

```
Organization updated = mergeToOrganization(jaxbOrganizationPojo, originalOrganization);
```

I really feel like I should start the `mergeToOrganization` method by making a protective copy of `originalOrganization` instead of directly mutating it. Direct mutation leaves me feeling dirty. But alternatives to that seem to be sketchy reflection or loooong get/set boiler plate code.

Ideas? Opinions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't see what's the problem with direct mutation as long as you handle transactions properly. But if you want to remove the entity from persistent context, assuming you're using JPA 2.0, you can use [EntityManager.detach()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#detach%28java.lang.Object%29). This way, technically, the entity will never be marked "dirty" and you don't have to feel bad about it. Also, make sure to use `merge()` to save it back and not `persist()`, or you'll get many nasty exceptions.

**EDIT** If you want to return a new copy of your entity, the most bullet-proof cloning method I've seen so far is to use ObjectOutputStream: http://javatechniques.com/blog/faster-deep-copies-of-java-objects/

Comment: It's not as much a problem I have with JPA, rather the general feeling that I should not directly mutate method parameters. But my parameters being JPA entities brings  a whole new set of problems to cloning them.

Comment: many thx for the deep copy java example I have used to copy entity object and create new ones (of course some more work required) but the basic things rely on the suggestion and example

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use your own clone() method, or if using EclipseLink the copy() API can be used.

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/AttributeGroup#Copy_Examples

Comment: I was hoping to avoid writing my own clone(), I think it's a bit error-prone and just an extra maintenance hassle. Unfortunately I'm not using EclipseLink but Hibernate underneath.